# Is org.hamcrest.io.FileMatchers included in any hamcrest build?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

The Hamcrest repo includes `org.hamcrest.io.FileMatchers` (see https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/tree/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/io) but it isn't present in the build artifacts `hamcrest-all` or `hamcrest-library` (v1.3). What happened to that matcher? Is it available in any JAR artifact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileMatchers` was [added in July 2012](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/commit/23a8337e4f332f9520a3547f4415882392dd6667), a few days after [Hamcrest 1.3 was released](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/releases/tag/hamcrest-java-1.3). As of September 2014, there hasn't been another public Hamcrest release. [Although there is demand for a 1.4, there's no roadmap for a release](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hamcrest-dev/NZ6DurYqgnc).

That class will be part of a 1.4 release but, until then, consider making a local build of Hamcrest or copying that single class into your project 
(or switching to [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/internal/Files.html)).

Comment: It's sad that Hamcrest seems to be nearly dead; such a great library but the activity is just so low.

Comment: There's an open ticket ([Make a release of Hamcrest 1.4](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/65)) which may be a good place to gauge progress or offer assistance.